# Can ORM ODB for C++ generate code from a database

Tags: c++, orm, odb

I am fairly new to this library, and ORM in general. I know tools like EntityFramework can generate code from a database. Can ODB for C++ do this work?

Comment: I created php script to create classes from MySQL tables, check it [here](https://github.com/crgarridos/cpp_odb_generator)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Looking at the [main page](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) of the project, there is an example how to use ODB. It seem that you need only add some `pragmas` here and there:

```
#pragma db object
class person
{
  ...
private:
  friend class odb::access;
  person () {}

  #pragma db id
  string email_;

  string name_;
  unsigned short age_;
};
```

but you do that on already present code, so no, it does not generate anything.

Comment: so what this means in the help of the odb, in windows: "--database | -d (db) Generate code for the database (db)"

Comment: that means you are generating the code between c++ and the db

Answer (score 2):

the [QxORM](http://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/home.html) maybe help you to this work. this library use for Qt framework.